# how to fetch content in web crawling

Tags: java, algorithm, web-crawler, scrapy

[image]

Hi! I am trying to implement this pseudocode  for **spider algorithm for exploring the web.** 
Need some idea for my next step of pseudocode : "**use SpiderLeg to fetch content**" , 
i have a method in another class **SpiderLeg** which has a method to get all the URLs of that webpage but wondering how can i use it in this class??

```
// method to crawl web and print out all URLs that the spider visit
public List<String> crawl(String url, String keyword) throws IOException{
    String currentUrl;
    // while list of unvisited URLs is not empty
    while(unvisited != null ){
        // take URL from list 
        currentUrl = unvisited.get(0);
       //using spiderLeg to fetch content   
        SpiderLeg leg = new SpiderLeg();
    }
    return unvisited;
}
```

---

Cheers!! Will try that...However I tried this without using queue D.S, it's almost working but doesn't stop the program while searching for some word.

And when it finds it shows just the link of Webpage not all the specific URLs where it finds the word. 
Wondering is it possible to do this way?

```
private static final int MAX_PAGES_TO_SEARCH = 10;
  private Set<String> pagesVisited = new HashSet<String>();
  private List<String> pagesToVisit = new LinkedList<String>();



public void crawl(String url, String searchWord)
  {
      while(this.pagesVisited.size() < MAX_PAGES_TO_SEARCH)
      {
          String currentUrl;
      SpiderLeg leg = new SpiderLeg();
      if(this.pagesToVisit.isEmpty())
      {
          currentUrl = url;
          this.pagesVisited.add(url);
      }
      else
      {
          currentUrl = this.nextUrl();
      }
      leg.getHyperlink(currentUrl);
      boolean success = leg.searchForWord(searchWord);
      if(success)
      {
          System.out.println(String.format("**Success** Word %s found at %s", searchWord, currentUrl));
          break;
      }
      this.pagesToVisit.addAll(leg.getLinks());
  }
  System.out.println("\n**Done** Visited " + this.pagesVisited.size() + " web page(s)");
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The crawling algorithm is essentially [Breadth first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search), you will need to maintain a queue of unvisited URL's and each time you visit a URL you de-queue it and you will need to en-queue any unvisited URL's that you find from your HTML parser (SpiderLeg).

The conditions for adding a URL to the queue are up to you but typically you would need to hold the distance of the URL's from the seed URL's as a stopping point so you aren't forever traversing the web. These rules may also include specifics on what you are interested in searching so that you only add URL's that are relevant.

Comment: Cheers!! Will try that ..however so far I tried this without using queue D.S , it does kind of work but doesn't stop the program while searching some word.

And when it finds it shows just the link of Webpage not all the specific URLs where it finds the word. Wondering is it possible to do this way?

Comment: Please open another question with your updated code/attempt